# Namespace in class-views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I can't manage to get the namespace name-id in a class view. Anyone knows?

What I wan't to do is filtering a queryset to get only the appropiate models to each namespace.

Here is the code I have:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    url(r'^art/', include('items.urls', namespace='art', app_name='items')),
    url(r'^electronics/', include('items.urls', namespace='electronics', app_name='items')),
)
```

**items.urls.py**

```
url(r'^items/$', ItemListView.as_view(model=models.MyItem), name='item_list'),
```

**ItemListView.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ItemListView(ListView)
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ItemListView, self).get_queryset()
        qs... # <- Here I want to filter for MyItem.namespace = namespace (!)
        return qs
```

Comment: I don't think namespaces are passed to any views. Isn't it just for reversing?

Comment: It's not the case but we can think about a blog app. If we want to use the same blog app for several users we can use namespace to get several instances of the app...
..but if we want to get only the posts written by the user we need to get the namespace in the queryset.

(Ok, I know that in the blog example we can use a url-param to get username, but in my case this would be a workaround, not a smart solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what namespaces are for, in this context. They're just to group views together for the purposes of reversing.

If you want to pass a variable to your view, you need to do it explicitly:

```
url(r'^/(?P<category>\s+)/items/$', ItemListView.as_view(model=models.MyItem), name='item_list'),
```